# Unable to load webview in tab view

Tags: android, webview, tabwidget, tabview

I have no idea why my webview is unable to load in my tabhost/tabwidget. For the tabhost/tabwidget, I am using the tutorial that was provided by Android Developer. Also, in my logcat, the warning seems to be at the tab1Activity.java, pointing the warning to "wv.loadDataWithBaseURL("http://lovetherings.livejournal.com/961.html", myString, "text/html", "UTF-8", "about:blank"); "

Below are my codes. Can anyone help me? Thanks so much in advance! :D

Here is my main.xml

```
    <LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="5dp">

    <TabWidget
        android:id="@android:id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        />
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        >
        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/webview"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            />

        </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

My main activity

```
public class HelloTabWidgetMain extends TabActivity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Resources res = getResources(); // Resource object to get Drawables
    TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();  // The activity TabHost
    TabHost.TabSpec spec;  // Resusable TabSpec for each tab
    Intent intent;  // Reusable Intent for each tab

    // Create an Intent to launch an Activity for the tab (to be reused)
    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, ArtistsActivity.class);

    // Initialize a TabSpec for each tab and add it to the TabHost
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("tab1").setIndicator("tab1",
                      res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_tab1))
                  .setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);

    // Do the same for the other tabs
    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, tab2Activity.class);
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("tab2").setIndicator("tab2",
                      res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_tab2))
                  .setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);

    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, tab3Activity.class);
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("tab3").setIndicator("tab3",
                      res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_tab3))
                  .setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);

    tabHost.setCurrentTab(0);
}
```

}

And my tab activity (where I would want my webview contents to be displayed)

```
public class tab1Activity extends Activity{

WebView wv;
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    try {
    URL url = new URL("http://lovetherings.livejournal.com/961.html");

    // Make the connection
    URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
        new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));

    // Read the contents line by line (assume it is text),
    // storing it all into one string
    String content ="";
    String line = reader.readLine();
    while (line != null) {
        content += line + "\n";
        line = reader.readLine();
    }
    reader.close();

    String myString = content.substring(content.indexOf("<newcollection>"));

    int start = myString.indexOf("<newcollection>");
    if (start < 0) {
        Log.d(this.toString(), "collection start tag not found");
    }
    else {
        int end = myString.indexOf("</newcollection>", start) + 8;
        if (end < 0) {
            Log.d(this.toString(), "collection end tag not found");
        } else {
            myString = "<html><body>" + myString.substring(start, end) + "</body></html>";
        }

        WebView wv = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview);
        wv.loadDataWithBaseURL("http://lovetherings.livejournal.com/961.html", myString, "text/html", "UTF-8", "about:blank");
    }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    // Display the string in txt_content
    //TextView txtContent = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt_content);
    //txtContent.setText(myString);
    }    
}
```

}

Please help me! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

In your layout XML, your root node (LinearLayout) needs a namespace attribute. Insert xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" as its first attribute. I'm guessing that your layout isn't inflating properly, causing the error when you try to do something with the WebView.

Comment: Nope, I actually did have that root node. Just that when I copied over to here, it disappeared, I might have missed out copying the root node.